Setting up reverse proxy in Nginx to allow php execution
I am experimenting with containing website using Docker, and I managed to get half of it work. Website works correctly with Nginx with this config:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
    }
}
upstream backend_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;

}

But when I try to add php snippet
 location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;  
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

it does not work, cannot find any .php file.
I tried with
        proxy_pass http://backend_server/;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000$uri;


But it does not matter.

You can't have proxy_pass and fastcgi_pass in the same location. How have you set up PHP? Is it listening on 8000, 8081, php8.1-fpm.sock, or backend_server?

PHP is listening at "php8.1-fpm.sock",  but I am not sure if I should change that since I am running different apps that are not proxied

So I changed fastcgi_pass to 127.0.0.1:9000; and made new .conf file in fpm/pool.d, set it to listen at 127.0.0.1, included it in php-fpm.conf and I am still getting "File not found".
But when I try "fastcgi_pass to 127.0.0.1:9000$uri" I am getting Internal server error, so there is some progress but I don't know what else I can do

fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000$uri is not valid syntax. Unlike proxy_pass, it only accepts an address and port, or a unix socket. You haven't set a root so $document_root is empty, which would explain why SCRIPT_FILENAME is not pointing to the correct pathname.

You named the upstream "backend_server" so you call it exactly like this.. "proxy_pass backend_server;" - the details are in your definition of that server.
